# Ethereum: verifying signatures despite malicious transaction data modifications

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum, secp256k1, js-ethereum-cryptography

Let's say we have this code to sign a simple transaction in **Ethereum** and then verify the signature, using the [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm), just like in real life:

```
const { secp256k1 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1");
const { keccak256 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/keccak");
const { toHex, utf8ToBytes } = require("ethereum-cryptography/utils");

const privateKey = secp256k1.utils.randomPrivateKey();
console.log('private key :  ', toHex(privateKey));

const publicKey = secp256k1.getPublicKey(privateKey);
console.log('public key  :', toHex(publicKey));

const transaction = { message: 'hello world!' };
const data = JSON.stringify(transaction);
const hash = keccak256(utf8ToBytes(data));
const signature = secp256k1.sign(hash, privateKey);
console.log("payload     :", { transaction, signature });
```

Then I send the `transaction` and `signature` through the network and use this code to recover the public key and verify the signature:

```
const pkHonest = signature.recoverPublicKey(hash).toRawBytes();
console.log('recovered   :', toHex(publicKey) === toHex(pkHonest));           // true
console.log('verified    :', secp256k1.verify(signature, hash, pkHonest));    // true
```

So far so good.

But what if I ([or someone in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) change the content of the transaction? You would expect the signature verification to fail, but it retrieves a different public key and the verification is successful.

```
const dataEvil = "modified";
const hashEvil = keccak256(utf8ToBytes(dataEvil));
const pkEvil = signature.recoverPublicKey(hashEvil).toRawBytes();
console.log('recovered   :', toHex(publicKey) === toHex(pkEvil));             // false
console.log('verified    :', secp256k1.verify(signature, hashEvil, pkEvil));  // true... why?
```

It doesn't seem right to me, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Usually you know what address (pub key) is supposed to sign the message and the purpose of the verification it to check if it's the same address.

Comment: Thanks @Igor. Does this mean that, in addition to verifying the signature, the public key (or the address) has to be sent in the body of the transaction and compared to the one recovered from the signature? I had read that for security reasons the public key is not sent, but retrieved from the signature.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with that signature. I.e., what is your goal? As you mentioned a transaction, it doesn't matter here as a wrong address makes the transaction invalid anyway so it's not included. For other use cases, like an auth with a signature, you exactly know who is trying to enter and ask for a signature from that specific address. And so on.

Comment: I am doing an [Ethereum Developer Bootcamp](https://www.alchemy.com/university/courses/ethereum), and I just want to learn the recommended way to sign and verify a transaction. I wrote this code that works to verify an honest transaction, then I tried to simulate a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and was surprised by the verification success, so I think that probably the verification process must be better than mine. So if you can improve my code in any way according to your experience, I will be very grateful.

Comment: It may depend on what exactly you're trying to solve, but it seems that you're looking for MAC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) but you better to ask this in a relevant SO community such as https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ because what you're asking is not specific to Ethereum at all

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can send the public key (or address) as part of the transaction body ([normally the address is sent instead of the public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78216379/4071001), I have simplified this example for convenience).

```
const transaction = {
  from: toHex(publicKey),
  to: '...',
  value: '...',
  nonce: 0
};
```

Then you can check the recovered public key as part of the transaction verification:

```
const getTransactionCount = from => 0; // TODO: Implement properly
const getBalance = from => 0;          // TODO: Implement properly

const { from, to, value, nonce } = transaction;
const recovered = signature.recoverPublicKey(hash).toRawBytes();

if (toHex(recovered) !== from) {
  console.error("Sender does not match");
} else if (secp256k1.verify(signature, hash, recovered) !== true) {
  console.error("Invalid signature");
} else if (nonce !== getTransactionCount(from)) {
  console.error("Invalid nonce");
} else if (getBalance(from) < value) {
  console.error("Not enough funds");
} else {
  console.log("Transaction verified!");
}
```