# Ethereum: how to generate a valid address from the public key?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum, secp256k1, js-ethereum-cryptography

I am using this code to generate a private key, public key and address, acording to [this](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/#account-creation):

> The public key is generated from the private key using the [Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm). You get a public address for your account by taking the last 20 bytes of the Keccak-256 hash of the public key and adding 0x to the beginning.

```
const { secp256k1 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1");
const { keccak256 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/keccak");
const { toHex } = require("ethereum-cryptography/utils");

const privateKey = secp256k1.utils.randomPrivateKey();
console.log('private key :  ', toHex(privateKey));

const publicKey = secp256k1.getPublicKey(privateKey);
console.log('public key  :', toHex(publicKey));

const address = keccak256(publicKey.slice(1)).slice(-20);
console.log('address     :', '0x' + toHex(address));
```

However, I get a valid private and public key pair, but not the corresponding address (compared to some online converters like [this](https://www.ethtools.online/eth-pub-to-addr) and [this](https://www.devoven.com/converting/eth-public-to-address)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in your code is that you generate the address on the basis of the compressed key, but it must be generated on the basis of the uncompressed key (0x04|x|y).
The leading marker byte has to be removed, from the rest, i.e. the 32 bytes x coordinate and the 32 bytes y coordinate, the Keccak-256 hash is generated, the last 20 bytes of which are the address.

Code with sample data:

```js
const { secp256k1 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/secp256k1");
const { keccak256 } = require("ethereum-cryptography/keccak");
const { toHex } = require("ethereum-cryptography/utils");

const privateKey = secp256k1.utils.randomPrivateKey();
console.log('private key        :  ', toHex(privateKey));               // c8aee432ef2035adc6f71a7094c0677eedf74a04f4e17227fa1a4155ad511047

const publicKeyComp = secp256k1.getPublicKey(privateKey, true);         // 0262117d6727ddd50b8f1d60ce50ef9fa511c7b43b6b6e6f763b32b942e515a4d4
console.log('public key - comp  :', toHex(publicKeyComp));

const publicKeyUncomp = secp256k1.getPublicKey(privateKey, false);      // 0462117d6727ddd50b8f1d60ce50ef9fa511c7b43b6b6e6f763b32b942e515a4d47df6eb61d3dceb615176c80a16484e773885f3de31e0344ed3d74cce103646f4
console.log('public key - uncomp:', toHex(publicKeyUncomp));

const address = keccak256(publicKeyUncomp.slice(1)).slice(-20);
console.log('address            :', '0x' + toHex(address));             // 0x9cea81b9d2e900d6027125378ee2ddfa15feeed1
```

---

Note that the current solution does not yet implement the checksum for Ethereum addresses ([EIP-55](https://github.com/ethereum/ercs/blob/master/ERCS/erc-55.md)).
This functionality is provided e.g. by the NodeJS package [eip55](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/eip55) and can be applied as followed:

```js
const { encode } = require('eip55')
...
const addressEip55 = encode('0x' + toHex(address));
console.log('address (EIP-55)   :', addressEip55);                      // 0x9cea81B9D2E900d6027125378ee2ddfA15FeEED1
```

---

This code now generates the same address as the website you referenced ([here](https://www.ethtools.online/eth-pub-to-addr)), if the public key (compressed or uncompressed, with leading marker byte) is specified there.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much, also for pointing out the eip55 library.

Comment: But if the compressed public keys are now the default and preferred over the uncompressed version, why is the address generated from the uncompressed public key? (this was the origin of my confusion in the first place)

Comment: @lcnicolau - Currently, x and y are used for the Keccak-256 hash (i.e. uncompressed key without 0x04 marker byte). x alone (i.e. compressed key without marker byte) is not unambiguous, as there are generally two possible y for an x (even/odd y, which is the motivation for the marker byte: 0x02 = even y, 0x03 = odd y), which means that the address would not be unambiguous either. In principle, the marker byte could also be used for the hash, but instead the decision was made to use the actual value y in addition to x.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good reason that I couldn't find anywhere else, so [I've created this question with a bit more context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78221282/4071001), and I'll be happy to accept your answer. I think others will find it useful as well.